# What programming languages support running in a limited manner for security and what proven issues complicate this?

Tags: security, lua, tcl, programming-languages

I want to allow user scripting/programming of server-side programs.  While I am seeking [advice](https://serverfault.com/questions/1080174/how-can-i-mitigate-the-risks-of-intentionally-allowing-users-to-run-code-on-a-se) on serverfault regarding how to mitigate security risks on the system administration side of things, I am also wondering what languages provide facilities to restrict them from executing dangerous code?

While I'll discuss Lua and Tcl, I am very interested in other options as well; I love to learn about new languages, and having a selection to choose from would be great from the standpoint of being able to pick one that would be ideal for users.

Lua:

Lua has a [sandbox](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-sandbox-in-lua) capability.

As an example of an issue that a developer may need to consider for Lua, there is [this](https://www.corsix.org/content/malicious-luajit-bytecode) page regarding Lua bytecode as a vector of attack.

Tcl:

Tcl has the ability to create "safe interpreters":
https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/interp.htm#M12

> If the -safe switch is specified (or if the parent interpreter is a safe interpreter), the new child interpreter will be created as a safe interpreter with limited functionality; otherwise the child will include the full set of Tcl built-in commands and variables.

I haven't been able to find much information regarding issues a developer may need to consider for Tcl.

What are other languages with similar capabilities and do they have any proven known issues in this regard?

Comment: In Java you would have an ability to configure your own SecurityManager, that would allow to run java scripts is some sandbox-like environment (has been used in java-applets on the browser side a longer while ago before the technology became obsolete).

Comment: I guess it makes sense Java would have such a feature; didn't even think about it, it has been ages since I last encountered a java applet.

Answer (score 1):

In Tcl with basic safe interpreters, all operations that touch the outside world at all (`open`, `exec`, `source`, `load`, `socket`, etc.) are profiled out of the safe interpreter — the commands that provide them are hidden (a special kind of naming that means that they cannot be accessed from inside the interpreter) — so it's trivially provable that by default there's only possible problems due to excessive memory or CPU use.

But what about how to actually let the safe interpreters do something useful?

Well, that's possible because every safe interpreter has a parent interpreter that is fully-enabled, and which can create inter-interpreter aliases: commands in the safe interpreter which invoke a defined stand-in in the controlling parent. It's good to think of those as being analogous to a system call (though much cheaper!) and they can provide exactly the operations that the application wishes to support. Of course, some substantial care is required if you take an argument to those commands that you intend to treat as a filename or network address, but you at least know that you only ever get poked at in ways that you expect. (The usual way to avoid problems with filenames is to only support abstract handles — simple names defined by the parent — that have no meaning other than “you can use this in these operations”. That's pretty much how Tcl's I/O channel handles work.)

There's also the full Safe Tcl built-in package, which provides a simulated full interpreter in a safe interpreter and which allows defined profiles of what can be accessed (e.g., just reading packages from a defined local package repository). I'm less certain that that's correct; it is quite complicated internally.

Comment: I hear tell (on Twitter) that a future version of Python may adopt some sort of similar approach. I'm _very_ uncertain how the details will work as Python values are very different in nature.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty solid approach, so far as I can figure.  I guess https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/safe.htm is the Safe package you mentioned?  It sounds like it makes efforts to obscure filesystem information as well, which seems pretty cool.

Comment: I came across a new language that seems to maybe take a similar approach, https://rhai.rs/book/about/features.html.

Comment: Regarding python's efforts, I found a dialect, Starlark, used for configuration: "Starlark is intended not for writing applications but for expressing configuration: its programs are short-lived and have no external side effects and their main result is structured data or side effects on the host application."  https://github.com/google/starlark-go/

Comment: Along the same lines, are dhall, a statically-typed functional configuration language: https://dhall-lang.org/,  and jsonnet, a functional configuration language that extends JSON https://jsonnet.org/.

Comment: I suppose one could be pretty safe with the configuration-language approach, at the cost of flexibility and a circuitous manner of exposing functionality to the user/scripter.

Comment: If you want to add information about further languages, give each one its own answer. You may self-answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My apologies, I'll do that.